# How to add a page break for a visualforce page rendered as pdf with column names appearing in new page as well

Tags: visualforce

How to add page breaks with the header names(column names) carry forwaded to the new pages as well for the visualforce page rendered as pdf having the information in the table.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: here is a good example -- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098sQIAQ

Comment: Hi kurunve,
I tried 
          
              -fs-table-paginate: paginate;  
but it is not working....

Comment: Hi kuruve,Thank you it worked....i was not using THEAD in my table before after adding THEAD its working.